# Is Tail recursive really powerful on C language?

Tags: c, tail-recursion

I think the [Tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is really helpful in functional programming language.
How about C?

- Does C language or compiler support **tail call elimination**?
- Do the program create new stack frame for the new call?

From wiki:

> Tail calls can be implemented without adding a new stack frame to the
> call stack. Most of the frame of the current procedure is not needed
> any more, and it can be replaced by the frame of the tail call,
> modified as appropriate (similar to overlay for processes, but for
> function calls).
>
> The program can then jump to the called subroutine. Producing such
> code instead of a standard call sequence is called **tail call
> elimination**.

Comment: It is not about C but about specific compilers. Most of modern compilers can optimize the tail recursion.

Comment: You realise that the very same wikipedia page you link to gives you examples of tail-recursion in C, right?

Comment: This seems like an opinion question, but tail recursion identification and elimination is very useful in any recursive application, including C, since it allows you to perform operations that would otherwise be limited by the stack size.

Comment: I'm working on small RAM size microcontroller. The tail recursive may make the implementation easier, but [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not specify tail recursion as part of the language at all. The only thing the C99 standard says about recursive function calls is:

> **6.5.2.2 Function Calls**
>
> 11 Recursive function calls shall be permitted, both directly and indirectly through any chain
> of other functions.

If a compiler can detect tail recursion and translate a recursive call as tail recursion, it can but it is not required to do so by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Tail-recursive is usually used in functional languages because it's natural way to implement loops on structures which are actually not that much recursive in procedural languages.

Therefore procedural languages don't need it. However, it's up to compiler to decide if it finds such optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the C Standard nor compilers have to support the tail recursion. It is implementation defined whether a compiler supports the tail recursion.

Comment: What do you mean by "supports"? It's a way of writing functions. Compiler can detect it and unroll. Or may not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I mean that it is not necessary that a compiler indeed generates object code that corresponds to the tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI (standard) C doesn't require tail recursion. Most C compilers implement it because the optimisation isn't very complicated and it provides a huge savings in stack and cache memory.

Pre-ANSI, however, C *definitely* supported tail recursion. It was done with `goto`:

```
fact(n,m) { m =+ n; n--; if(n) goto fact; return n; }
```

Note other oddities: `+=` was spelled `=+` and `int` is the default for all variables. Source code examples of pre-ansi C are uncommon now, but the [v6 ed.c](https://github.com/geocar/ed-v6/blob/master/ed.c.orig#L28) notably uses this method for error handling.

Comment: what is the difference between =+ and += ?

Comment: x+=y was spelled x=+ y (note the space is required)